# How to get BEST_Sales from Bloomberg for next 2 years via python?

Tags: python, bloomberg

I tried:

```
from xbbg import blp
blp.bdh("AAPL US Equity", "BEST_Sales" , "BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE", "2GY", "2021-08-01")
```

And

```
blp.bdh(tickers='AAPL US Equity', flds=['BEST_Sales', "BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE", "2GY"], start_date='2018-10-10')
```

It doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: OP did show from the jump what they have tried so far, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
blp.bdh('AAPL US Equity', 'BEST_Sales', "2021-08-01", BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE="2GY")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).